# Airflow : Is it possible to place CPU and RAM constraints before DAG execution

Tags: resources, airflow

Is it possible to place CPU and RAM constraints before DAG execution . I understand we can put restrictions in containerized tasks .
But is it possible to enforce these constraints at DAG level or at individual task level ,while using normal python operators ?

Comment: It seems KubernetesPodOperator is better, if you wish to limit resource useage.

Comment: I'm working in a non-containerized environment

Comment: came across cgrouptaskrunner . However very little documentation available currently